# GIT installation - no choosing the SSH executable step

Tags: git

I'm trying to install GIT, the newest version. 1.8.4.3. 
I want to use Plink, but after i choose use git bash only, i don't have another window with choosing SSH only last window with line ending... can anyone know why?